# Как изменить формат дат в List<DateTime>?

Tags: c#

Добрый день, есть List, при попытки вывести все его элементы листа после дат еще добавляется время: "01.03.2017 0:00:00". Вопрос: можно ли изменить формат хранения дат в List на "01.03.2017" (без времени) или это возможно только при выводе элементов с помощью MessageBox.Show(item.ToShortDateString()); ?

Comment: а как вы даты в вещественных числах хранить собираетесь?

Comment: `double` в формате `yyyy.mm.dd`? Воу-воу!

Comment: Мне не нужен формат DateTime, просто нужно чтобы все элементы в листе поменяли свой вид на вышеуказаный и стали double, если вы про это.

Comment: В вещественных числах нет две(?) дробных части...

Comment: в duble - это невозможно. точка.

Comment: Блин действительно, я и не подумал об этом сразу. Спасибо

Comment: @Maccord чем вас `DateTime` не устраивает?

Comment: Теперь полностью устраивает, я по невнимательности проглядел одну важную вещь. Я совсем недавно на stackoverflow, подскажите, мне стоит задать новый вопрос про DateTime или лучше изменить этот?

Comment: @Maccord подправьте лучше этот

Comment: @AGS17 исправил

Comment: @Maccord зачем вам изменять формат дат? Чем вас в таком случае строка не устраивает?..

Comment: Все элементы листа будут использованы на оси x для построения графика С помощью ZedGraph, и вполне вероятно что все даты будут отображаться с временем, что будет занимать дополнительное место. Просто хотел подстраховаться.

Comment: Ну так и используйте массив строк,который у вас сейчас...

Comment: Хорошо попробую, извините если вопрос глупый, никогда с DateTime не работал.

Comment: Если стандартный вывод `DateTime`, полученный с помощью вызова метода `ToString`, вас не устраивает, то придётся вручную указывать как выводить (например, с помощью того же самого метода `ToShortDateString`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тип `DateTime` не хранит формат своего отображения. Он просто хранит дату в виде целого числа типа Int64.

Формат отображения задаётся при выводе данных пользователю. Многие визуальные компоненты имеют встроенные возможности формата вывода показываемых данных.

Например, имеется список:

```
var list = new List<DateTime>();
```

Если привязать его к `ListBox`

```
listBox.DataSource = list;
```

дата/время будут выводиться в формате по умолчанию, то есть просто вызовом метода `ToString`.

У листбокса можно задать формат вывода:

```
listBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
listBox.FormatString = "dd.MM.yyyy";
```

После чего будет показываться только дата, без времени.
Похожим образом задаётся формат, например, в `DataGridView`: `DefaultCellStyle.Format`.

Если данные нужно показывать в компоненте, который не имеет настроек формата или передавать их на обработку куда-то ещё, то можно конвертировать их в строковое представление нужного формата.

```
var list2 = list.Select(dt => dt.ToShortDateString()).ToList();
```

Теперь, при привязке к `ListBox` с форматом по умолчанию, данные будут в желаемом виде, ведь это просто строки.

На представленном скриншоте три `ListBox`. В левом `DateTime` отображается в формате по умолчанию, с временем. В среднем использована установка формата, к правому привязан список типа `string`, с заранее конвертированными значениями. Как видим, результат в обоих идентичный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]